# ExampleMatcher match by list contains

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I've got an entity

```java
public class Part {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "automotiveparts_sequence", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "automotiveparts_sequence",
            sequenceName = "automotiveparts_sequence",
            allocationSize = 50
    )
    private Long id;

    private OffsetDateTime creationDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Catalog catalog;
}
```

I want to search parts by example, but I want to search only when the catalog is active. So first I search for active catalogs then I want to do some matching by fields that I ignore for now because I know how to do it, but I also want to search only by catalog.id contained in the list of ids from found active catalog. How can I achieve that?

```java
List<Catalog> catalogs = catalogRepository.findAllByState(CatalogState.ACTIVE);

ExampleMatcher customExampleMatcher = ExampleMatcher.matchingAny()
                .withMatcher("vdi4081.id", ExampleMatcher.GenericPropertyMatchers.exact())
                .withMatcher("catalog.id", match -> match.transform(s -> s.))
```